# unfortunately activity has stopped android

Tags: android

I'm doing a code to write the TextView, but when I click the application gives error:

> unfortunately aulanewboston1 has stopped.

I create activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Here's the code and error shown in the console

```
package com.br.aulanewboston1.boston;

import java.util.Random;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;


public class TextTela extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.text);
        Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResult);
        final ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbpassword);
        final EditText senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtextsenha);
        final TextView display =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        passTog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(passTog.isChecked()){
                    senha.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD); 
                }else{
                senha.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            }
        }
    });
        chkCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                String check = senha.getText().toString();
                display.setText(check);

                if(check.contentEquals("left")){
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                }else if(check.contentEquals("center")){
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }else if (check.contentEquals("right")){
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }else if (check.contentEquals("blue")){
                display.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                }else if (check.contains("WTF")){
                    Random crazy = new Random();
                    display.setText("WFT");
                    display.setTextSize(crazy.nextInt(75));
                    display.setTextColor(Color.rgb( crazy.nextInt(265), crazy.nextInt(265), crazy.nextInt(265)));
                    switch(crazy.nextInt(3)){
                    case 0: 
                        display.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        display.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        break;
                    }

                    }else {
                    display.setText("invalido");
                    display.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    display.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

        }

  });

}

}
```

Error message

```
[2012-06-29 20:09:39 - NewBoston] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { 
    act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
    cmp=com.br.aulanewboston1.boston/.Tema }

[2012-06-29 20:09:39 - NewBoston] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, 
    its current task has been brought to the front
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you accidentally hit the home key when running the activity which pushed it into the background, then when you went to tap on the icon of your app, Android brought it into the foreground. That error is pretty normal :) Nothing to worry about, when its in the foreground running in front of you, hit the back key and that should end the activity.

Answer (score 0):

When you donot make a change to your project code. no change in java files, xmls, drawables etcs and you press Play button of eclipse to run your application.

Then, if your application is already running either in foreground or in background. Eclipse will not upload and install new copy of your application to device/emulator. But, it will bring already running `Activity` to the front and will leaves a message for you in console telling you that it has brought current ativity to front.